# Updating the data source then reload CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` which has a cell inside with increment and decrement buttons, those buttons will be affecting the `numberOfItemsInSection` of the `collectionView`.

This is how `numberOfItemsInSection` looks like:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.customizationsCount
}
```

I have set a property `customizationsCount` of type `Int` which will change according to the increment and decrement as this:

```
private var customizationsCount = 1 {
    didSet {
        if itemsCustomizationCollectionView != nil {
            DispatchQueue.main.async { self.itemsCustomizationCollectionView!.reloadData() }
            self.view.layoutSubviews()
        }
    }
}
```

**The problem is**: This is updating the collectionView's `numberOfItemsInSection` first, and then it's updating the data inside of the cells.

I need to add new data to update the model, and then update the data source.

Is there any possible way to do so?

Comment: You can not update a cell before your datasource if they are both connected to the same. You can however update a visible cell before you update your datasource. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618056-visiblecells **You can however** use multiple datasources, 1 "Datasource" for returning the number of items and 1 datasource for returning the data for the cells.

Comment: @Sneak Thanks for the help